# Difference in rendered texture and model texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, edit-mode

So i applied a smart uv unwrap and the image texture seems to be different in rendered and non rendered. The first view is perfect, but the linked image below is still completely buggered. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: also i never made a seam cut in the object, does that matter?

Comment: There's some information missing, what render engine, what material looks like, is object scale applied (Object mode > CTrl+A), are there any UV vertices in UV map pineed (UV editor > Select all > Alt+P) etc.

Comment: http://s345.photobucket.com/user/DaOrkyBitz/media/full_zpswwtorfbm.png.html